# Unable to save value of customer attribute in magento2

Tags: customer, magento-2.2.5, customer-attribute, save, edit-form

I am trying to edit customer form data in which i have added one contact number as attribute in form.
On removing the text from contact number and then saving it i am not able to save null or empty string in database after form is submitted.

Code: `$customerDto->setCustomAttribute('contact_number',NULL); $this->customerRepository->save($customerDto);`

Is there any other way to save custom attribute value of customer to null or empty string on form submit

Answer (score 0):

This might be a limitation based on the **is_required** attribute property. When this is set to false(0), the attribute is not seen as required and could be set to null.

Answer (score 0):

your attribute should look like

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'partner_id_microsoft', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'MPN ID',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1001,
                'position' => 1001,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);
            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'partner_id_microsoft')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create'],
            ]);

            $attribute->save();
```

while saving data to customer you have to use:

```
//get post value for partner_id_cisco
            $customer->setCustomAttribute('partner_id_cisco',$partner_id_cisco);
```